# DataTemplate inside DataTemplate - ListBox inside ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, collections, binding

I want to use dataTemplale inside dataTemplate.
I want to display data in list box like that:

```
<RoomName>
    <Kid Name>
    <Kid Name>
<RoomName>
    <Kid Name>
<RoomName>
    <Kid Name>
    <Kid Name>
    <Kid Name>
```

This is what I got. It's not working.

```
class Room
{
  ObservableCollection<kid> Kids = new Ob...
}

class School
{
  ObservableCollection<Room> Rooms = new Ob...
}

class kid
{
  Name;
  Size;
  (...)
}
```

This is my binding from code:

```
School BigSchool = new School();
MainListBox.DataContext = BigSchool;
```

This is my Window XAML:

```xml
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Rapideo_Client" mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Class="Rapideo_Client.MainWindow"
        Title="Client" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="400" Width="625">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="kidTemplate" DataType="Kid">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Size}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="roomTemplate" DataType="Room">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Kids.Count}"/>
                <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Kids}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource kidTemplate}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" x:Name="MainListBox" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource roomTemplate}" />

</Window>
```

Comment: Please explain "it's not working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a ListView with grouping?  Then you could use a single ListView with one data template for items and one for the group.  Just set a GroupStyle on the ListView and it will do exactly what you want.

An example:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Uid="DataTemplate_4" x:Key="MetadataGroupDisplayTemplate">
    <TextBlock x:Uid="TextBlock_4" Text="{Binding Path=RoomName}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

```cs
GroupStyle gs = new GroupStyle();
gs.HeaderTemplate = FindResource("MetadataGroupDisplayTemplate") as DataTemplate;
MyListView.GroupStyle.Add(gs);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) (read this!) only works with public properties, in your code i only see fields.

Also if that is not it, check the Output window of Visual Studio for binding errors, also check [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) for more info on databinding debugging.